# Should exported types always be moved to seperate file?

Tags: typescript

I don't like the idea of having a file with both export type SomeType ... etc. (can be multiple) and an exported class.

But my colleague argues that its a desired way to do this, when this exported type is used within the certain functionality.

For me having to go through multiple exported types definitions until I reach the class itself is not readable. I would always move those to seperate files. But he says different. Is there an official guideline here ?

Comment: You can find multiple style guides by just googling and discuss those with your colleagues, but every company/project can have it's own style guides/conventions and that's absolutely tolerable.

Comment: @MikeS. I know styles guides can differ, I'm asking about best practice not the generic response 'it depens' lol